# Overrided wildfly default logging with logback doesn't log to console

Tags: logging, wildfly, logback

I overrided default WildFly logging by putting in META-INF dir jboss-deployment-structure.xml with following content:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- exclude-subsystem prevents a subsystems deployment unit processors running on a deployment -->
        <!-- which gives basically the same effect as removing the subsystem, but it only affects single deployment -->
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and also put logback.xml with following content:

```
<configuration debug="true">

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<appender name="scriptgenToolAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>scriptgenTool.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>TRACE</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %logger{0}: %msg%n%ex{full}</pattern>
        <outputPatternAsHeader>false</outputPatternAsHeader>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>archive/scriptgenTool_.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="scriptGenTool" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="scriptgenToolAppender"/>
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="scriptgenToolAppender"/>
</root>
```

So, all logs are writing in file, but nothing into console (STDOUT appender). Is it possible to make this logs console printable?

Comment: Do you see messages with the logger name of `stdout`? Something like `16:02:43,926 INFO  [stdout]`.